# nvim after directory not working or sourcing properly

Tags: neovim

I've set up my nvim rc or whatever it's called (am newbie).

```
.config/nvim/init.lua
.config/nvim/after/hello.lua
.config/nvim/lua/username/init.lua
```

I've set them both to print a message "from init", from "username" and "from hello"

both `init.lua`s work, but `after/hello.lua` does not print its message. I've confirmed in `:help rtp` that my nvim does search the `nvim/after` directory for run files.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: What is your code like? You need to provide a MWE for people to help you. Do not make people guess. Also after directory is often used to override settings in other files, you are using it wrongly, see `:h after-directory`.

Comment: My code is simply a print("from hello"). It works fine for the init.lua and the lua/username/init.lua, just not the after/hello.lua

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue as you (fellow noob here) but after adding a sub dir /nvim/after/plugin and placing my "hello" file in there, nvim found it without a require statement - hopefully this is not too late and that it helps.

Comment: This helped. But why?

Comment: Extract from `lua-guide-config` nvim help section:

"If you'd like to run any other Lua script on |startup| automatically, then you
can simply put it in `plugin/` in your |'runtimepath'|."